# Create ?lang=ua in htaccess (homepage)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, lang

I have. Htaccess, which displays  **only the main page** and language `?lang=ua` style.

I want to redirect (using code 301) asks `site.com` to `site.com/?lang=ua` with `RewriteEngine`.

**site.com => site.com/?lang=ua**

I tried this:

```
    Redirect 301 ^$ http://site.com/?lang=ua
    or
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/?lang=ua [L]
```

Displays error "***Wrong redirect to a page***"
But still not working! How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify which URL format the user enters, and which you wnt to see in the end?

Comment: Hello! Need to "site.com => site.com/?lang=ua" - only on the main page. Several times did RewriteRule and Redirect. Displays error - "Internal Server Error" and "Wrong redirect to a page". Still does not work(( How to make a redirect? Waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of the "^" and "$" in `Redirect`, it doesn't take a regular expression to match. This will do:

```
Redirect 301 / http://site.com/?lang=ua
```

EDIT: 
Now that I'm thinking about it, this will loop indefinitely because the query string isn't being checked. What you need is this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=ua($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ http://site.com/?lang=ua [L,R]
```